# Bug in markup preview

Tags: bug, markdown

As always, before opening a topic, I warn other users not to directly downvote the question without reading it!

---

I obviously met an issue in the markup previewer.
Enter EDIT (for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31476046/2377343)) and you will see that these symbols `=>` are incorrectly designed:

1. Screenshot 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nQfy.png
2. Screenshot 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/29qwp.png

Comment: I'd put good money on that being an issue with the whitespace characters being used, and not the markup preview...

Comment: What's the dealio with this prefatory remark about downvoting a question without reading it? What prompted you to include that, and is it really necessary? How is it relevant to this question?

Comment: @CodyGray If OP decided so, then it means that he faced that problem. OP.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the characters are tabs instead of spaces, so it's somewhat expected that they won't always align perfectly. Use spaces to do alignment.

Comment: ["Only a moron would use tabs to format their code."](https://blog.codinghorror.com/death-to-the-space-infidels/)